Где хранить переменные в игре?
Я пишу 2d игру на движке godot4.
В игре есть переменные, например скорость. В игре есть возможность прокачиваться, соответственно переменная скорости должна изменяться. Где её тогда хранить, чтобы можно было в любой момент менять и изменения сохранились? Может быть все подобные переменные храниь в json файле?

Хранить так, как удобно) можно и в файле, можно и в базе в облаке, если нужно дать возможность играть с любого устройства с удобством. Зависит от требований.

Т.е. получается если у меня мультиплеер, то лучше хранить в базе?

даже и в сингл плеере можно хранить в базе. Нужно смотреть на то, что хотим дать игрокам.
